# iOS development with new AIR 2.6

Tags: actionscript-3, ios, air

I've just read AIR 2.6 release notes:
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/03/everything-new-in-adobe-air-2-6.html

Did I understood correctly that On-device debugging over USB is implemented only for Android OS?

What is the simpliest way to port my air app to iOS? Can someone provide a step-by-step tutorial on how to deal with it?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Renaun's blog](http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/debug-air-apps-on-android-with-flash-builder-4/) about this topic, it's really great, and using the [sample project](http://renaun.com/flex4/DebugDemo.fxp) makes very easy to understand and adopt the approaches.

The debugging part is a bit tricky, for it to get work i found the following sites helpful: 
[Corlan's blog](http://corlan.org/2010/08/)
[Debugging a mobile AIR application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffa.html)